# Is there way to skip automatic logout on promise rejection

Tags: admin-on-rest

I am using admin-on-rest (1.3.2) and trying to skip the default behaviour of calling AUTH_LOGOUT action on Promise rejection. I want to drop my behavior.

I found an issue on their Github Issues:
https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/issues/894, but without much information about the implementation here.

In the browser console, I see that executed saga is here:
https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/v1.3.2/src/sideEffect/saga/crudResponse.js#L92-L97

Comment: The automatic logout only happens when the authClient is called with `AUTH_CHECK` and rejects its promise: https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/v1.3.2/src/sideEffect/saga/auth.js#L53

Comment: I see that AUTH_LOGOUT is called when API returns an error. Which actually makes the logout, the next AUTH_CHECK is not passing, because of that. My question is how to skip those AUTH_LOGOUTs caused by error.

Answer (score 1):

I've just realized why what AUTH_LOGOUT happening.
My AUTH_ERROR check:

```
 if (type === AUTH_ERROR) {
    const { status } = params

    if (status === 401) {
      localStorage.removeItem('admin')

      return Promise.reject()
    }
  }
```

Does not have check for other status codes rather than 401 and there was no Promise.resolve returned, which leads to Promise.reject('Unknown method') returned.